# Radio buttons and textboxes in Flash SWF disappear on IE

Tags: internet-explorer-6, adobe, flash

I have developed a Flash application for a client (wedding RSVP) and implemented it on the web. She complains that the textboxes and radio buttons disappear on IE6. Can anyone confirm this for me?

http://toolboxstudio.co.za/phoebe/

Please don't submit the RSVP, as I don't want to spam my client, but please just tell me if you see the radio buttons and if you can fill out the textboxes.

Thanks a heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wouldn't be with IE6, but with her version of the flash player perhaps.  What version are you targeting?  How are you embedding the file?  Have her go to http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15507.html and verify the version she is using.

On another note -- http://ie6funeral.com/ --

Comment: Thanks, I think it was her FP version.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have IE6, but it looks fine on OCX FF3.5.8 and Safari4 :)

Have you tried [Litmus](http://litmusapp.com/) for cross-browser testing?